# Ripple effect does not restore the color of Navigation Drawer api 24

Tags: android, ripple

I have an issue with an ripple effect and navigation drawer. In api < 21 when i press the recyclers view item, the item highlights and restores after to its previous color. 
In api >= 21 the highlited color remains until I click on some other space.
What could it be?
`v21\custom_bg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/mask"
        android:drawable="@color/colorDrawer">
    </item>

</ripple>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution. I tested my app on api 24 which is buggy. After I changed api to 23 it started to work.